# JQuery - Toggle() -- using TR Class but need action from Image

Tags: jquery, image, toggle

Working through a bit of clean up on some JQuery.

I have a situation where I need rows to collapse using JQuery Toggle.  I found a great example here on SO where you use TR Classes to set the outer boundaries of  toggle range.

That works great however every element in the TR is "clickable", such as TDs containing financial amounts.

Worked up a function that Prepends and image to the first column.  That image should be the only thing clickable to toggle.  The image itself swaps between states (display "+" or "-") when clicked.

I think the best approach is to have the Class Selector focus on the IMG in the first TD.  But I cannot get the syntax right.  I wonder that since the image is injected by Prepend is that causing issues.

I tested briefly the idea of making the Row Toggle reside within the Function for the Image Swapping but ran into issues.

Here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/novadar/Gnnue/94/

Here is the slightly working Function:

```
// Enable Row Toggle
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".rowToClick").click(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil(".rowToClick").toggle();
    });
});
```

Here is a function focusing on the first TD but does not toggle properly (only toggles the remaining columns in the TR).

```
// Enable Row Toggle  toggle from first cell
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".rowToClick td:nth-child(1)").click(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil(".rowToClick").toggle();
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image is a grandchild of the row, you need to navigate up to the grandparent for the toggle code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".rowToClick td:nth-child(1) img").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".rowToClick").nextUntil(".rowToClick").toggle();
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Gnnue/95/)

Comment: Barmar.  Thank you.  I knew I was close.  I could not quite make out the relationship.  I was thinking it was on par with the TD where it resides.

Comment: I think `$(this).closest('tr')` will be better

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks. I've changed it to `.closest(".rowToClick")`, so it's consistent with the selector used to find the image.

Comment: Thanks for the new details.  My JQuery/Javascript journey has been interesting. There are so many different ways to accomplish the same goal.